# When does this SSL certificate expire?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509

Below are the results from testing the SSL certificate at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=bungalowsoftware.com
[image]

It looks like we have two certificates.  Am I reading that right?
Does the SSL service  (CloudFlare.com) that's using   the certificate point to a particular Certificate?

Comment: you are seing: #1 : the (only) certificate, and #2+#3+#4 is the chain of the CA (certificate authority) that signed (and here allows the browser to validate) that certificate : whenever one of those 4 expires first will be the time where that certificate becomes unusable. Here, #1 expires first. in #1 you can see "Issuer: E1". in #2 you can see the E1 CA, which itself was issued by: "ISRG Root X2". #3 shows that "ISRG Root X2" CA, which itself was issued by: "ISRG Root X1" (which appears under #4, and could itself be issued by one or more further along the chain, & all should be present+valid)

Comment: in addition the certificate (#1) could also become unusable if it is "revoked", i.e. if it's fingerprint is listed in a revocation list named, for that #1 certificate, "OSCP", which should also be included in the chain (and as it is not listed in there, it is"Good (not revoked)". This can be used for exemple if one discover that certificate "foo" was not legit and should not be allowed : they include it in the certificate's "revocation list", which is part of the way the certificate from an authority are created and signed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a **certificate chain**, which:

- starts with the **server certificate**
- continues with **intermediate certificates**
- until you reach a certificate which is recognised as an authorised CA certificate (a so-called "**root certificate**") by your system

Your system trusts certificates issued by the root certs it trusts, and their "children" (provided each intermediate cert is itself authorised to issue certificates).

- The certificate for `bungalowsoftware.com` (**server cert**, #1) expires on 2024-04-26. It was **issued and signed by `E1`**.
- The certificate for `E1` (**#2, intermediate cert**) expires on 2025-09-15. It was **issued and signed by `ISRG Root X2`**.
- The certificate for `ISRG Root X2` (**#3, intermediate cert**) expires on 2025-09-15. It was **issued and signed by `ISRG Root X1`** (but **ISRG Root X2 is usually already in your system's certificate store**).

**Your certificate chain is valid until the earliest one in the chain expires**, and that would be (quite logically) your server cert, which expires on **2024-04-26**, in a bit over 2 months.

This is quite normal for a Let's Encrypt certificate, they last 3 months and a new one is usually issued about every 2 months.

Comment: Does Let's Encrypt automatically update the certificate for me?
Or do I need to do something every 2 months?  (I don't think I've touched it in a year or so)

Comment: @ClayNichols something on the server must renew the certificate. From what I understand you are using CloudFlare, I’m not familiar with their offerings but it’s quite possible they do that automatically for you. It was definitely renewed on January 27, so if you didn’t do it, there is a process doing it (which is the normal way when using Let’s Encrypt, you don’t want to have to do something like that manually every two months).

Answer (score 8):

What I can see here in the screenshot is an X.509 cert chain for a domain bungalowsoftware.com.

Typically the server during TLS handshake will send the leaf cert and intermediate CA certs - between 1 and n. The root CA cert technically could be sent as well, but I don't think this is a common practice.

You can see the same thing using `openssl` in your terminal:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect bungalowsoftware.com:443       
Connecting to 172.67.139.219
CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=2 C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X2
verify return:1
depth=1 C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN=bungalowsoftware.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN=bungalowsoftware.com
   i:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E1
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Jan 27 00:26:00 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Apr 26 00:25:59 2024 GMT
 1 s:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E1
   i:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X2
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 384 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
 2 s:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X2
   i:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 384 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
 3 s:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 20 19:14:03 2021 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
...
```

Expiry date of your leaf cert is Apr 26 00:25:59 2024 GMT.

Comment: So the one expiring April 2024 was created from Let's Encrypt (and apparently January 27th of this year?

Comment: That's what it looks like. Let's Encrypt certs are 90 days only: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#what-is-the-lifetime-for-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-how-long-are-they-valid

Comment: Note that the effective expiration date of a certificate chain is equal to the earliest date of all certificates in that chain, including the root -- but a CA would be daft to issue a leaf certificate with a later expiration date than one of its parents. Wouldn't surprise me if it happened at least once though.  (Interestingly, it might even be happening here, since the X1 cert that signed the X2 cert appears to expire before it.)

Comment: Regarding sending the "root" certificate: SSLLabs will actually show you a *mild warning* if you are sending the root certificate along with the leaf and intermediates. The idea is that sending the root certificate is wasteful since it should be in every client's root store already. The intermediate certificate already contains the identity of the signing certificate (the root).

Comment: @Miral In theory, the validity of a leaf cert can change without anything happening at leaf level. After all, a cert with some not-after date is just a statement "I, the issuer, am confident that the signer holds a matching private key and assume that nothing bad will happen until [not-after]; otherwise, you'll learn that it is revoked (but after [not-after], I won't bother revoking it)". By this logic, any intermediate cert having passed its not-after date makes the leaf cert not trustworthy. However, nothing prevents a different chain to be built up, according to which it remains valid

Answer (score 7):

That certificate expires on 26 April 2024.

The other certificates are the intermediate CAs *E1* (Let's encrypt) and *ISRG Root X2*, and the root CA *ISRG Root X1* trust anchor bundled in the certificate chain. Those are not yours.

A browser might show another, cross-signed root CA ISRG X2. Intermediate CA certificates should be bundled and sent along, root CA shouldn't as some mobile clients won't like them and it's of no use anyway as trust anchor need to be present in the client.

Comment: ISRG Root X2 is also an intermediate CA in this case.

Comment: @user23204747 Funny, that's what SSLLab shows me as well, but all my local browsers show "ISRG Root X2" as self-signed, ie. root CA.

Comment: Your browser, indirectly depending on the browser and the OS - and directly on the root of trust / cacerts - might be showing you another X2 cert as a root. Likely the one expiring in 2040. That's a different one from the one listed in openssl output. That's cert cross-signing at play. I suppose browser will show you the shortest path it could validate, while openssl will show you what was received during TLS handshake. These can be different things.

Comment: "root CA shouldn't as some mobile clients won't like them" - Except for some *very* obscure edge cases, a TLS client will ignore a root cert supplied by the TLS server. That is the basis of the x509 trust model.

Answer (score 0):

Your ssl labs output is showing the whole chain, the root certificate which was used to issue the certificate and the certificate itself. This is how the trust chain of a certificate works. So look at the top part the first date, that's when your certificate will expire.

If you have a Linux terminal with openssl available you can also fire up this command

```
DOM="www.domain.com"
PORT="443"
printf Q | openssl s_client -servername $DOM -connect $DOM:$PORT \
| openssl x509 -noout -dates
```